# Sending ipython to the background with control-z

Tags: ipython

I frequently need to access the shell directly. In the past few weeks, every time I've used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to send an ipython task to the background and tried to resuscitate it with `fg`, it has failed.  I suspect this has to do with some recent change in ipython.  Is there any way to make ipython foregroundable again?

EDIT: ipython version 2.2.0, and the failure is that the terminal hangs and never recovers.  All I can do after `fg` is send ipython to the background again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then `kill` it.

EDIT: Apparently this is a problem with anaconda: if I try to start ipython, it insists on wrapping it in a shell and then a `python.app`:

```
37463 ttys008    0:00.00 /bin/bash /Users/adam/anaconda/envs/astropy27/bin/python.app /Users/adam/anaconda/envs/astropy27/bin/ipython
37464 ttys008    0:00.40 /Users/adam/anaconda/envs/astropy27/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python /Users/adam/anaconda/envs/astropy27/bin/ipython
```

so it appears that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is sending only one process to the background, perhaps?  Is there a reason for this behavior, and can I disable it?

Comment: As my ipython works perfectly stopping and resuming, I suppose that you'd better specify ipython version and platform

Comment: What do you mean "it has failed"? Do you have a traceback? The terminal gets stuck? The terminal dies? Could you please elaborate the concept to the bare minimum?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround has been posted here:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/191

You can either `kill -CONT {pid}` explicitly before using `fg`, or (better), use `fg %{jobid}`.  The former required that I also `reset` the terminal, while the latter just worked.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/191
did not work for me, but I managed to workaround by below alias:

```
alias ipython='python -m IPython'
```